# How find the count integers that are divisible by 7 in the given range using only While loop

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

---How write a program that will get A and B inputs and the numbers in the [A, B] range will be divisible by 7 without the remainder... using while loop in C++...---

For Example:

Input data: 7 13

console result: 1

Input data 5 21

console result: 3

Input data -8 -5

console result: 1

---

C++ code example with for loop

int main() {

int a, b,i,count;

input >> a >> b;

count = 0;

for(i = a; i <= b; i++) {

if(i % 7 == 0)

count++

}

}

Comment: Can you explain where you are stuck on solving this? What have you tried?

Comment: Perhaps pick just one language.

Comment: Well, the first decision you need to make is in which language you're going to write this program, C++ or Javascript. You used both tags for your question.

Comment: What is "input" in "Input >> a >> b"? Everything seems okay, but I'm not sure what that's supposed to do. Is this pseudo-code or your actual code? What does your compiler say is the problem?

Comment: this is the pseudo code, and i need write this code with while loop

Comment: I need find count the number of divisions with while lool in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is pseudo-code or actual code, but the main mistake I see here is that you've used 'input' and I'm not sure what that's supposed to be. See the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int count=0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    cin >> a >> b;
    for(int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        if(i % 7 == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << count;
}
```

I replaced your 'input' with 'cin'. Then, I added an output of the 'count' variable so that we could see the result.

Now, to take it further and use a while loop, you just need to manually count:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int count=0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    cin >> a >> b;
    while (a <= b) {
        if (a % 7 == 0) {
            count++;
        }
        a = a +1;
    }
    cout << count;
}
```

So, we simply need to say while a is less than or equal to b, do the same thing as before. But, make sure that you increase a, or your loop will go on forever!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: thank You very much!!! 
You helped me a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct in terms of pseudo code. Do you want the negative number to be included or not?

Anyway, I am counting negative numbers also.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a, b, i, count = 0;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    i = a;
    while (i <= b)  // While loop
    {
        if (i % 7 == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << "Count: " << count << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but i'm need to write the same code with While loop